# Why doesn't my template work with JSONDecodable

Tags: swift, templates, swift4, codable

I'm using the new Swift 4 Codable interfaces to do a simple fetch of JSON data from a web service.  I've tried to implement a generic type method to handle decoding (so I don't need custom methods) but I keep getting an error.  Here is the code

```
extension StarWarsAPI {
public func decodeJson<T: Codable>(fetchUrl: URL, modelType: T, completion: @escaping (_ modelObject: Codable?, _ error:StarWarsErrorType?) -> Void){

    //guard modelType is Codable else {return completion(nil,nil)}

    var fetchRequest = URLRequest(url: fetchUrl, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)

    fetchRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
    fetchRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
    ]

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let fetchDataTask = session.dataTask(with: fetchRequest) { (data, response, error) in

        guard error == nil else {
            return  completion(nil, StarWarsErrorType.urlResponseError(error: error))
        }
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
            return  completion(nil, StarWarsErrorType.NilUrlResponseError())
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            return  completion(nil, StarWarsErrorType.noDataFound)
        }
        guard httpResponse.statusCode > 199 && httpResponse.statusCode < 300 else {
            return  completion(nil, StarWarsErrorType.httpErrorCode(code: httpResponse.statusCode))
        }
        var modelObject:Codable?
        do {

            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            modelObject = try jsonDecoder.decode(modelType.self, from: data)
            return completion(modelObject, nil)
        }catch{ // do nothing }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(nil, nil)
            }
        }
    }

    fetchDataTask.resume()
}
```

The Error reads "Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '(T, from: Data)'" .   Here is a screenshot of the error.

What am I missing?  Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type passed in to `decode(_:from:)` needs to be known statically. `modelType.self` is a dynamic instance of `modelType`, but its type isn't constrained statically; you'll need to use `T.self`, which is the statically known type.

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thank you for the fix and the explanation!  Not sure . how to mark this question as answered.

Comment: @RMH Glad to help. For instructions on how to mark your question as answered, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work